# typo3 display language switcher

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I'm trying to create a language switcher. I've found few examples but can't make It work.

For example I tried to use that code in TS:

```
  lib.languageMenu = HMENU
  lib.languageMenu {
  special = language
  special.value = 0,1

 1 = TMENU
 1 {
wrap = <ul class="langMenu">|</ul>
noBlur = 1
NO = 1
NO {
  linkWrap = <li class="menu-item normal">|</li>

  stdWrap.override = English || Deutsch
  stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
}

ACT < .NO
ACT {
  doNotLinkIt = 1
  linkWrap = <li class="menu-item active">|</li>
}

# NO + Translation doesn't exist
USERDEF1 < .NO
USERDEF1.doNotLinkIt = 1

# ACT + Translation doesn't exist
USERDEF2 < .ACT
USERDEF2.doNotLinkIt = 1
 }
}
```

I created an `<ul class="langMenu">` in my header.html, which is in partials, but It's empty. What Am I missing, how can I make It visible ?

[image: typo3 template]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by changing `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.languageMenu" />`

With:

```
<!-- ###LANGNAV### Start -->

<!-- ###LANGNAV### End -->
```

Then check into TS to find where "subparts" is and add:

```
LANGNAV < lib.languageMenu
```

This should be it.

Comment: Where exactly should I paste it ? I did into the `<ul>` but I just can see that as a string. I've seen something about fluid templates, but I guess I don't have a fluid templat, just normal html.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what kind of template do you have into the html?

Comment: I see, basically you have the old version of templating so you have to create  a new ###NAV### an put it there then you have to go to the template typoscript and create a new subparts and copy the typoscript to it.
This tutorial explains it a little bit better:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TemplatingTutorial/Tasks/WorkingHTML/MarksSubparts/Index.html#add-marks-subparts

Comment: could you possible make an example on the code I pasted ? I'm totaly lacking the knowledge of typo3 and I need to finish it as fast as possible.

Comment: Oh god, thanks. I've been trying to do that, but not in the subparts, and with  `###LANGNAV###`  .